# Replace EF LINQ query containing group by with SQL query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

We have an EF LINQ query with JOINs and GROUP BY and COUNT as below.

```
    var subgroupquery1 = from sg in _dbContext.SubGroups
              join e in _dbContext.Admins.Where(e => e.Status.StartsWith("Active") && e.SubGroupCode != indivsubgroupcode)
                on sg.SubGroupCode equals e.SubGroupCode
              join mf in _dbContext.MasterSetups.Where(e => groupstoinclude.Contains(e.AdminGroup)).Select(mfs => new { mfs.RefCode})
                on e.EntCode equals mf.RefCode
              group e by sg into g
              select new SubGroupInfo
              {
                  SubGroupKey = g.Key.SubGroupCode,
                  SubGroupCode = g.Key.SubGroupCode,
                  SubGroupName = string.Concat(g.Key.Name, " (", g.Key.SubGroupCode, ")"),
                  MasterGroupCode = g.Key.MasterGroupCode,
                  NoOfEntities = g.Count(),
                  Managers = g.Select(x => x.Manager).Distinct(),
                  Officers = g.Select(x => x.Officer).Distinct(),
                  ClientType = g.Key.ClientType,
                  Coordinator = g.Key.Coordinator,
                  GroupDate = g.Key.Group_Date
              };
```

The tables being queried have large number of columns.
EF is generating a complex SQL query and unnecessarily selecting all columns making it slow and  memory heavy.

I am trying to convert this LINQ query to SQL query, something like below. But I am not able to select the columns after grouping. Can someone help to complete the query please?

```sql
    SELECT sg.SubGroupCode, sg.MasterGroupCode, sg.ClientType, sg.BillingCoordinator, sg.Billing_Date, sg.[Name]
    FROM vw_W360_SubGroup sg
    JOIN vw_W360_EntityAdmin e ON sg.SubGroupCode = e.SubGroupCode
    JOIN vw_W360_MasterFileSetup mf ON e.EntCode = mf.RefCode
    GROUP BY sg.SubGroupCode, sg.MasterGroupCode, sg.ClientType, sg.BillingCoordinator, sg.Billing_Date, sg.[Name]
    SELECT
        {
            -- how to select the columns to return values like LINQ query
        }
```

Comment: Omit that last SELECT, you do not need it. The select in your linq is the equivalent of the first select in your sql statement. I recommend you capture the output from your linq statement at run time, you can do that with a profiler or in your code. You can then use that as a basis for the manual statement you are creating. That said I would strongly recommend you get the query plan and analyze that first to see exactly what part of the query is slow. It might be something easy like a missing index that is causing the problem.

Comment: There is no direct translation of this query to SQL. Especially for fields  `Managers`. and `Officers`

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing a SELECT query, all the columns that you want to select and return should be only on the your first SELECT statement.

```
SELECT 
    sg.SubGroupCode, 
    sg.MasterGroupCode, 
    sg.ClientType, 
    sg.BillingCoordinator, 
    sg.Billing_Date, 
    sg.[Name],
    e.EntCode -- If you want to select columns from your joins, you should do it like this.
FROM vw_W360_SubGroup sg
/* <Your type of join> */ vw_W360_EntityAdmin e ON sg.SubGroupCode = e.SubGroupCode
/* <Your type of join> */ vw_W360_MasterFileSetup mf ON e.EntCode = mf.RefCode
GROUP BY sg.SubGroupCode, sg.MasterGroupCode, sg.ClientType, sg.BillingCoordinator, sg.Billing_Date, sg.[Name]
```

Different Types of SQL JOINs
Here are the different types of the JOINs in SQL:

- (INNER) JOIN: Returns records that have matching values in both
  tables
- LEFT (OUTER) JOIN: Returns all records from the left table,
  and the matched records from the right table
- RIGHT (OUTER) JOIN:
  Returns all records from the right table, and the matched records
  from the left table
- FULL (OUTER) JOIN: Returns all records when there
  is a match in either left or right table

You can select the type of join more suitable for your scenario.

References:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp